# Efficiency of ordering the elements of a numpy array, by occurrences in a different array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

def suborder(x, y):
    pos = np.in1d(x, y, assume_unique=True)
    return x[pos]
```

`x` and `y` are 1d numpy integer arrays, and the elements of `y` are a subset of those in `x`, and neither array has repeats. The result is the elements of `y`, in the order they appear in `x`. The code gives the result I want. But the intermediate array `pos` is the same size as `x` and in many use cases `y` is much, much smaller than `x`. Is there a way I can more directly get the result without allocating the intermediate array `pos` so as to save some memory?

`x` is not sorted. In my case its elements are the ids of objects and are the value 0->len(x) but in an unspecified order, and it's sorted in order of a score assigned to each object. The purpose of `suborder` is to order subsets with that same score order.

`x` is around 10million elements; and I have many different values for `y`, some approaching the size of `x`, all the way down to just a handful of elements.

Edit: I get `x` from doing an `argsort` on a set of scores for objects. I had imagined that it would be better to sort once for all scores, and then use that ordering to impose an order on the subsets. It may actually be better to take `scores[y]`, then `argsort` that and take the elements of `y` in that order (for each `y`).

Comment: Is `x` sorted? If not, then the operation needs to iterate over all the values of `x` anyway. Thus, creating and filling `pos` may not be the bottleneck. Is the purpose to save some memory? If so, there are ways to do that but at the expense of a certainly much slower execution. How big are `x` and `y` in practice?

Comment: I've edited the question to include that information.

Comment: So you're trying to save about 10 megabytes? That doesn't seem all that important.

Comment: Well - times the size of a single int - which is actually 4 bytes in my case.  But I take your point, however I call this routine for many different instances of `y`, so it's multiplied by the number of ys (although it's transitory until the intermediate `pos` are garbage collected).

Comment: @PaulRudin efficiently searching for example 100K~1M items in 10M items that are not sorted without allocating big temporary arrays is challenging. The cost to pay in term of performance will certainly be quite big. That being said, I do not understand your point about multiple calls: if your code is sequential, then the array should be directly collected thanks to reference counting (it may not be freed from the OS PoV though but reused by the allocator). Another question: is the maximum value of `x` small and is it bounded?

Comment: I've edited to add that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

Since items are in `range(0, len(x))` and are all unique (ie. permutation), then you can preallocate only one buffer of size `len(x)` (`len(x)*4` bytes in RAM). The strategy is to first build reverse indices once just after sorting `x`:

```
idx = np.array(len(x), dtype=np.int32)      # Can be reused after each sort of `x`
idx[x] = np.arange(len(x), dtype=np.int32)  # Can be filled chunk-by-chunk in a loop if memory matters
```

Then, you need to filter the `y` array so all values are in `range(0, len(x))`. If this is already the case, then skip this step. The operation can be done using `yFilt = y[np.logical_and(y >= 0, y < len(x))]`. Since `y` can be quite big, you can do this operation chunk-by-chunk. A simpler, faster solution and more memory-efficient solution would be to filter `y` on the fly using Numba.

Then, you need to compute `x[np.sorted(idx[yFilt])]` to reorder items of `y` like in `x`. This can be done in-place using the following code:

```py
# Should not allocate any temporary arrays
idx.take(yFilt, out=yFilt)
yFilt.sort()
x.take(yFilt, out=yFilt)
```

After that, `yFilt` is now ordered like the items in `x`. Note that you can mutate `y` so not to perform any temporary array allocations (although this means `y` is not used by something else in the code after this operation).

This reordering algorithm runs in `O(Ny log Ny)` time with `Ny = len(y)`. The pre-computation runs in `O(Nx)` time with `Nx = len(x)`. It requires `4 (Nx + Ny)` bytes space for the out-of-place implementation and `4 Nx` bytes for the in-place version that perform *no allocation* to reorder `y`.

---

### Solution 2

If the previous solution takes too much memory for you, this solution should be the good one despite being much more computationally intensive. It uses only `O(8 Ny)` bytes (`O(4 Ny)` for the in-place implementation) and runs in `O(Nx log Ny)` time. Note that the output array can be preallocated once (and only filled later) to avoid any issue with the GC/allocator.

The idea is to perform a binary search of each value of `x` in a sorted+filtered version of `y`. Values are appended on the fly in an output array. This solution requires Numba or Cython to be fast (although a complex pure-Numpy implementation using chunks and `np.searchsorted` can be written).

```py
import numba as nb

# `out` can be preallocated and passed in parameter to 
# avoid allocations in hot loops
@nb.njit('int32[:](int32[:], int32[:])')
def orderLike(x, y):
    sorted = np.sort(y)  # Use y.sort() for an in-place implementation
    out = np.empty(len(y), np.int32)
    cur = 0
    for v in x:
        pos = np.searchsorted(sorted, v)
        if pos < len(y) and sorted[pos] == v: # Found
            out[cur] = v
            cur += 1
    return out[:cur]
```

Comment: This works. As I mentioned at the end of my edited answer, I'm also looking at sorting the overall scores rather than dealing with the argsort() of the overall scores. I'll do some timings/ memory allocation analysis for these two solutions and that alternative approach at some point and report back.

Answer (score 0):

`in1d` starts with:

```
if len(ar2) < 10 * len(ar1) ** 0.145 or contains_object:
            ...
            mask = np.zeros(len(ar1), dtype=bool)
            for a in ar2:
                mask |= (ar1 == a)
        return mask
```

In other words it does an equality test for each element of `y`.  If your size difference isn't that large, then it uses a different method, one based on concatenating the arrays and doing a `argsort`.

I can imagine doing using `np.flatnonzero(ar1==a)` to get the equivalent indices, and concatenating them.  But that will preserve the `y` order.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to get the elements of `y` in `x` order, so it doesn't immediately work. But it does suggest that it may be worth special casing the small `y` case to scan `x` once and collect the occurrences of `y` along the way.